# Redux localStorage is slow so useEffect runs before it

Tags: reactjs, redux

So I'm working on a project where the localStorage sets some information on storage (that can be changed), and based on that I'm fetching stuff from an API/DB, but the problem is that localStorage is not ready when the useEffect is called.

So this problem occurs only for the first time then works, what do I mean by that? So when the user first time visits the website, and the localStorage is just filled then this doesn't work, but if he goes and refreshes that page, then it will load, because it is already there in localStorage the data.

Here is my hook effect:

```
useEffect(() => {
      getData(`${view}_${language}`);
  }, [view, language])
```

`getData` calls a database with the information from localStorage that is set up in Redux, for example, the parameters can be like this: videos_english, but is not taken from the storage. The state `getData` returns is null.

Here is my Language state (the view state is the same too):

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const localLanguage = localStorage.getItem('language') || localStorage.setItem('language', 'English')

export const languageSlice = createSlice({
    name: "language",
    initialState: { value: localLanguage },
    reducers: {
        languageSwitcher: (state, action) => {
            switch (action.payload) {
                case 'English':
                    state.value = 'English'
                    localStorage.setItem('language', state.value)
                    break;
                case 'German':
                    state.value = 'German'
                    localStorage.setItem('language', state.value)
                    break;
                case 'French':
                    state.value = 'French'
                    localStorage.setItem('language', state.value)
                    break;
            }
        },
    },
});

export const { languageSwitcher } = languageSlice.actions;
export default languageSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use useState hooks. First declare `[language, setLanguage]` and call `setLanguage` inside of `useEffect` hooks with empty dependency that should be called first time. when `setLanguage` is called with `localStorage` value then `language` will be changed and second `useEffect` will be called as there is dependency of view and language. Here is the example:

```
const [language, setLanguage] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
   setLanguage(localStorage.getItem('language'));
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
   getData(`${view}_${language}`);
}, [view, language])
```